# RHEL + how to know the limit of concurrent connections number per port?

Tags: linux, networking, postfix, redhat, netstat

how to know the number of concurrent connections per port on RHEL 7.x machines

for instance, let say we connect to port 9080 with XXXX concurrent connections.

```
wget  http://server_mngmnt.jupiter.com:9080 &
wget  http://server_mngmnt.jupiter.com:9080 &
wget  http://server_mngmnt.jupiter.com:9080 &
wget  http://server_mngmnt.jupiter.com:9080 &
wget  http://server_mngmnt.jupiter.com:9080 &
.
.
.
```

second - what could be the results of huge concurrent connections to port 9080 ?

from my machine

```
more /etc/security/limits.conf


# End of file
* soft nofile 25000
* hard nofile 25000

sysctl -n fs.file-max
500000

ulimit -n
63536
```

Comment: Whats the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `what could be the results of huge concurrent connections to port 9080?` isn't that what web servers do? Also hugely dependent on application load and server transport. A background call to a simple web service could scale into tens or hundreds of thousands of connections.

Comment: the root cause that I am trying to solve is when response time VIA port takes much more time then usual.  for example - wget  http://server_mngmnt.jupiter.com:9080

Comment: @KingDavid, first will be wise to correct the hostname. Underscore symbol (`_`) is not permitted.

Comment: about the hostname its just example its not as my real hostname

Comment: @KingDavid Post your configuration and ask *that* question then?

Comment: the required details from my server posted also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper limit of how many connections a listener can support depends on the lowest limit imposed by:

- the application that is listening
- the limits the OS sets for the application creating the listener with regards to the number of open file descriptors (`ulimit -n` )
  that can be per session, in a systemd service unit file, `/etc/security/limits.conf` etc.
- the limits the OS / Linux kernel sets for the number of open file descriptors for all applications combined  `sysctl -n fs.file-max`
- the amount of avialable memory

and possibly others.

---

The number connections a client can make will be similarly restricted by the number of open file descriptors, available memory and the number of available ephemeral ports.